# onNewIntent not called after tapping to another NFC enabled device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, nfc, ndef

I'm coding in c# with Xamarin. I tried to share data over NFC from one device to another.

Open browser -> Options -> Share -> App4 to MainActivity

Both of my devices are running the same app and I'm tapping my device to the other device, but nothing happens.

I think it can't reach to `onNewIntent()`.

Did I miss something? I have been confused and keep searching for a week.

Here is my code:

```cs
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Nfc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App4
{
    [Activity(Label = "App4", MainLauncher = false, Icon = "@drawable/icon",LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSend , NfcAdapter.ActionNdefDiscovered }, Categories = new[] {
    Intent.CategoryDefault,
    Intent.CategoryBrowsable
    }, DataMimeType = "text/plain")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        string share;
        PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
        IntentFilter ndefDetected;
        IntentFilter[] intentF;
        TextView testTV;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);  

            Intent Myintent = new Intent(this, GetType());
            Myintent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
            mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, Myintent, 0);
            ndefDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ActionNdefDiscovered);
            try
            {
                ndefDetected.AddDataType("text/plain");
                ndefDetected.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
            }
            catch { };

            intentF = new IntentFilter[] { ndefDetected };
            NfcAdapter NA = NfcAdapter.GetDefaultAdapter(this);   

            if (NA!=null && NA.IsEnabled)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Nfc Found", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Nfc Not Found", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            testTV = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text_view);
            share = Intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraText);  
            testTV.Text = share;   
    }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();

            NfcManager manager = (NfcManager)GetSystemService(NfcService);
            NfcAdapter adapter = manager.DefaultAdapter;
            adapter.DisableForegroundNdefPush(this);
            adapter.DisableForegroundDispatch(this);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();


            var result2 = new byte[NdefRecord.RtdText.Count];
            NdefRecord.RtdUri.CopyTo(result2, 0);

            NfcManager manager = (NfcManager)GetSystemService(NfcService);
            NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TnfAbsoluteUri,new byte[0], new byte[0], System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(share));
            manager.DefaultAdapter.EnableForegroundNdefPush(this, new NdefMessage(record));
            manager.DefaultAdapter.EnableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, intentF, null);
        }

        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {

            base.OnNewIntent(intent);
            testTV.Text = "onNewIntent";        
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="App4.App4" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"></uses-permission>
    <application android:label="App4"></application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are missing something: You registered the foreground dispatch to listen for NDEF messages of the type "text/plain", which means you either expect a Text record or a record with the MIME type text/plain.

```
ndefDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ActionNdefDiscovered);
ndefDetected.AddDataType("text/plain");
ndefDetected.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
intentF = new IntentFilter[] { ndefDetected };
manager.DefaultAdapter.EnableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, intentF, null);
```

However, your app pushes an absolute URI record with an invalid (empty!) type name.

```
NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TnfAbsoluteUri,new byte[0], new byte[0], System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(share));
manager.DefaultAdapter.EnableForegroundNdefPush(this, new NdefMessage(record));
```

In order to match the intent filter, you would need to push a Text record instead:

```
byte[] text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(share);
byte[] language = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("en");
byte[] payload = new byte[1 + language.Count + text.Count];
payload[0] = (byte)language.Count;
System.Array.Copy(language, 0, payload, 1, language.Count);
System.Array.Copy(text, 0, payload, 1 + language.Count, text.Count);
NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TnfWellKnown, new List<byte>(NdefRecord.RtdText).ToArray(), new byte[0], payload);
manager.DefaultAdapter.EnableForegroundNdefPush(this, new NdefMessage(record));
```

Comment: Btw,how to use NedfRecord.RtdText like your code? I'm using  NdefRecord.CreateTextRecord("en", share) now. Because there is a error:  "Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<byte>'to'byte[]' "
.I try to copy it to a new byte[]:result2. Will it works?

Comment: @wuken My update should do the trick, though it might not be the most efficient solution. Btw. `NdefRecord.CreateTextRecord` is the prefered method (and essentially wraps what my code does). However, that method is only available starting with API level 21, while your manifest suggests that you require API levels 10+.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help again!